# Изменение размера окна с сохранением пропорций

Tags: java, swing

Как сделать так, чтобы при ресайзе окна оно сохраняло свои пропорции высоты к ширине?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить обсервер соответсвующего ивента, самый простой вариант будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
  public class SynchronizedBoundsFrame extends JFrame
  {
     public SynchronizedBoundsFrame ()
     {
        addComponentListener ( getBoundsListener () );
     }

     public static void main ( final String [] args )
     {

        final JFrame jFrame = new SynchronizedBoundsFrame ();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        jFrame.setSize ( 300, 200 );
        jFrame.setVisible ( true );
     }

     private ComponentListener getBoundsListener ()
     {
        return new ComponentAdapter ()
        {
           @Override
           public void componentResized ( final ComponentEvent e )
           {
              // get component
              final Component component = e.getComponent ();
              final Rectangle bounds = component.getBounds ();

              bounds.height = bounds.width;
              component.setBounds ( bounds );
           }
        };
     }
  }
```

По большому счету вам нужно такой компонент листенер обьявить в отдельном классе, в консрукторе ему задавать что к чему синхронизировать и соотношение. Он будет работать для любой компоненты.